# How to set session in one method and get the session data in another method in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

This function will get the session value

```
public function getSession(){
    $value =Session::get('email');
    var_dump($value) ;
}
```

this function use to set the session values

```
public function setSession(){
    Session::put('email', 'aaaaaaa.com');

    $value=Session::get('email');
    var_dump($value);

}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('store','Product@setSession');
Route::get('display','Product@getSession');
```

when type display in url it's show NULL

Comment: What version of laravel are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use Laravel 5.2 probably you have to set your routes under the `'web'` group to be able to use the session.

In fact, Laravel initializes the Session in the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` middleware, that is grouped under the `'web'` middleware group ( as you can see from the `Kernel.php` file )

So, to use the session, your routes should use that middlware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('store','Product@setSession');
    Route::get('display','Product@getSession');
});
```

Besides, i suggest you to close the request cycle properly, to be sure that the session will be set, for example:

```
public function setSession(){
    Session::put('email', 'aaaaaaa.com');
    $value=Session::get('email');

    //this will end the request-lifecycle 
    return Response::json(['result' => 'ok']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will install laravel 5.2 freshly, you can see in the route file a middleware ['web'] is added which comes under \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class , and if you will use the session under that group in route, session will work fine there or if you are using any other group, then you have to use that middleware.